# IM on an isolated network?

Tags: untagged

I need to set up an IM system for a network that won't be connected to the internet - probably just a number of laptops connected via wireless.  There will be a central server.  What options do I have for clients and server software?  Open source or free would be preferred.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[XMPP](http://xmpp.org/software/servers.shtml) (Jabber) servers work just fine without an internet connection.  I use [ejabberd](http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/) and it works quite well, but there are a number of other options for both Linux and Windows servers.

XMPP also has excellent [client](http://xmpp.org/software/clients.shtml) support, including most of the "alternative" IM clients like Adium, Miranda, Pidgin, etc.

Comment: Agreed - jabber is the way to go. Check out the Openfire jabber server. It's free, and *very* easy to set up.

Answer (score 3):

You could also go for IRC, the Internet Relay Chat. There are several opensource servers and a lot of clients for windows and linux (like mIRC or irssi).

We use IRC at our company, where we have most of NOC and Servicedesk in a channel, so questions or announcements can be broadcasted to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Vypress chat for years as a private IM system. It works great on a LAN with no inet. Per there web site, there are .nix ports of the client.

http://www.vypress.com/products/chat/